# NSURLSessionUploadTask doesn't send the whole file

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I came into an issue trying to send files with `NSURLSessionUploadTask` to a custom REST service.
The problem is that the file seems to get transferred up to an arbitrary size, and then the task stops without any error (`URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:` gets called with `error` set to `nil`).

The file that needs to be transferred is almost 10MB in size, and I found that smaller files sometimes get transferred correctly.

The code I'm using for creating the task is the following:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"100-continue" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Expect"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:instanceFilePath];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [self.session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:fileUrl];
```

I need to specify some headers for the server to correctly interpret the request, and the `length` variable is the effective size of the file being sent.

Any idea about what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you logged the output of URLSession:task:didSendBodyData:totalBytesSent:totalBytesExpectedToSend: as you will be able to check if there is a mismatch in the content-length header that you're setting and what the delegate has determined to be the content-length

Comment: Yes, I did. That's the method I use to track transmission progress. The totalBytesExpectedToSend parameter correctly matches the length of the file, but the totalBytesSent doesn't get past the 44% of it, in the tests I've made...

Comment: Can you log the incoming connection on your REST service?

Comment: Actually, the problem was on the server side. A size limit was set and the uploaded files exceeded that limit. Thank you!